# Change event is called by default in page load - knockout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to save the value when user changes the dropdown option by using ajax call. This is my dropdown

```
<select data-bind="options: RefreshOptions, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Key', value: RefreshSelectedValue,  event: { change: SaveRefreshValue }"></select>
```

I am binding the dropdown values. But the problem is change event **SaveRefreshValue** function is calling by default(page load). 
I tried using **optionsCaption: ' '** its works fine. But it adds one empty value in dropdown which is not needed.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What are you going to do if the user actually *wants* the first option from the list? Knockout won't trigger a change again if the select doesn't change its value, so the user has to first select *another* option and then return to the actual option... Sounds to me like triggering the AJAX call upon applying bindings is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If `RefreshSelectedValue` is just a `ko.observable()` with no value, then the first item in the dropdown array will be **SET** to it. That will cause your change event to fire.

Also use `subscribe` instead of change for dropdowns in KO. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1620/).

**Update**: If you are adamant on not adding an `optionCaption`, then I can suggest a hack (it's not very pretty, but does the job): Create a `counter` for how many times dropdown is changed as a global variable. Then if the count is more than one, do your ajax: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1625/)

```
var dropdownChangeCount = 0;

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.RefreshSelectedValue = ko.observable();
    self.RefreshOptions = ko.observableArray([
         new RefreshModel({ id: "1", name: "Refresh1" }),
         new RefreshModel({ id: "2", name: "Refresh2" })]);

    self.RefreshSelectedValue.subscribe(function (selectedValue) {
        dropdownChangeCount++;
        if (dropdownChangeCount > 1) {
            alert("changed manually, not called on load");
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have used Ajax call in onchange event. If i use Subscribe, it will lead the ajax call, thats why Subscribe is not used here. I need to call the ajax when user changes the dropdown manually

Comment: @Vetri subscribe takes a function. So you can do whatever you are doing inside the `change` function inside subscribe's function

Comment: If you are adamant on not adding a `optionText`, then i can suggest a hack (it's not very pretty, but does the job): Create a `counter` for how many times dropdown is changed as a global variable. Then if the count is more than one, do your ajax: https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1625/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to have a caption and do not want anything selected at first, use the `valueAllowUnset` binding option:

```
<select data-bind="
    options: RefreshOptions, 
    optionsText: 'Value', 
    optionsValue: 'Key', 
    value: RefreshSelectedValue, 
    valueAllowUnset: true"></select>
```